# Request Body for Form recognizer

Tags: json, request

I was looking at this documentation sent to me by the microsoft squad when I signed up for form recognizer and I was hoping someone could tell me what the request body would look like for this.

https://westus2.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/form-recognizer-api/operations/AnalyzeWithCustomModel

I have a trained model an i was able to set up the working call with Postman

Answer (score 1):

I am able to get it working in Postman by setting the **Body** to use *form-data* and a PDF file. Add the **form** key and the value should point to the PDF file you are analyzing:

[image: Postman Body]

I also set the request headers to have **Content-Type** of *text/plain* and included my subscription key with the **Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key** setting:

[image: Request Headers]

Hope this helps!